# Explorer in Windows 10 hanging on Azure Files SMB operations

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, samba, azure

At home, I have a fully up-to-date Windows 10 Pro desktop. I have also created an Azure Files SMB share in the cloud. I am able to connect to the cloud drive from the desktop without issue, and read files without issue.

However, any write operations (create, delete, modify...) performed **from Windows Explorer** result in the operation hanging at 99%, even though the operation is performed successfully. Operations from other machines, or programs on the same machine, work successfully. So for example:

- Creating text file from Ubuntu machine on same network, works
- Writing text in that file from Notepad in Windows, works
- Renaming or deleting that file in Explorer, hangs (but the operation is completed, can be checked/checksumed from elsewhere)
- Creating a new file or folder from Explorer, hangs (but file is created)

The hang looks like this:

[image]

And the only way out is to either kill the window, which usually restarts Windows Explorer (observed by watching the taskbar reload), or to wait 2 or 3 minutes, which seems to "complete" the operation (even though the operation is done as fast as one would normally expect, a second or two).

I have thought of all the usual culprits:

- Permissions - Cannot be, since the changes do take place
- Network - Not this either, since other apps in same machine, and other machines in same network, can make changes successfully
- Some SMB error - I do have another SMB drive in the local network which I am able to write to without issue. My only thought is that Azure Files uses SMB 3, and my local share is probably on SMB 2 (shared from a Raspberry Pi)

At this point I'm out of ideas. How can I troubleshoot this issue? Surely an all-Microsoft setup should work without issue :D

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Try to check the `System event log` for any related error messages.

Comment: @Jackdaw thanks for the suggestion! I checked the System log, but there were no obvious issues reported.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug Microsoft is looking into for us. The Azure and Windows teams have looked multiple times into our environment. They are not advertising that this is a bug affecting thousands of customers. For us it has to do with accessing Azure files over a VPN, when explorer hangs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This gives me some hope, I was starting to think I was the only one facing issues with this one.